# Which is better option to compare time in php? "strtotime" OR "new DateTime"

Tags: php, time

I need to compare two times for further operation.

First I have compared the time with `strtotime`

```
$time1 = "09:00 am";
$time2 = "11:09 am";

$one = strtotime($time1);
$two = strtotime($time2);         


if($one > $two)
{
    echo "<br>"; 
    echo "yes";

} else {
   echo "<br>"; 
   echo "no";
}
```

Then I have tried with `new DateTime()`

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('09:00 am');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('11:09 am');

 if($datetime1 > $datetime2){
      echo "YES";
  } else {
      echo "No";
  }
```

Both gives same result but which is most efficient and more reliable way to **compare time** in php.

Comment: [This simple test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b360e33ae0f738e4c5a5a24d39daf371c9fda593) shows `strtotime` winning by about 2*10^-8 which is probably negigible.

Comment: @apokryfos correct sir. I am comparing larger time data here so I have just out of curiosity asked here which function I can more relay. and thanks for the valuable comment sir.